# Drawing Graphics not working on Form load event

Tags: c#, draw

```
        private void DrawIt()
        {
            System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
            System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(
              50, 50, 150, 150);

            graphics.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, rectangle);
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DrawIt();

        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DrawIt();

        }
```

when putting the 'DrawIt' method in a button event it works, but in a form load event it doesn't, why?

Comment: try to add DrawIt() method to Form_Shown() event

Comment: Get rid of CreateGraphics and use the OnPaint override.

Comment: @LarsTech thats way too advance, im a beginner :P

Comment: No it's not.  Write `protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {...}`  Use the `e.Graphics` for your drawing.  When you need to paint again, call `this.Invalidate();` elsewhere in your code.  The problem with CreateGraphics is it is a temporary canvas that will erase what was drawn by other overlapping forms or by minimizing and restoring the form.

Comment: I had the same problem, [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx) microsoft example helped me a lot.
It uses the Paint event as other answers mention and uses a picture box to contain the elements being drawn.

Answer (score 3):

Change Load event to Paint.
If you want redraw your form use this.Refresh();

When you are in Paint method use:

```
private void mForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Load event is run before the Form is drawn. So anything you draw is overwritten by the Form.

Call your DrawIt method from an event which fires after the Form has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to an event to trigger DrawIt(). You can use a panel or sth else. Then write an OnClik event. Your drawing will start after a click.

Answer (score 0):

if vb6 just add call to your sub or function in Form_Activate

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Form_Load event use Form_Shown event. That should work.